# Setup simultaneous auto-click for testing

Tags: sync, input

My company has a contact form on their website, that allows users to attach files and send them to us.

This usually runs without incident, but every now and then files from individual users get mixed up. We have run extensive tests on our end and the data does not get mixed up behind the firewall. 
The only other possibility is the code for the contact form somehow mixing things up when users send us files simultaneously. 
Naturally the providers of that code says they will not look into this until we are able to reproduce the error.

I want to set up at test system that allows me to send data from three different PC's(virtual) at "the same time"(I know there is not such thing hence the "")

I've been looking in to autoclick software but havent been able to find anything that meets my needs.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Old article](http://lifehacker.com/260445/automate-timed-mouse-clicks-with-clickwhen) but the software works and can still be downloaded. Maybe sync all computers to a central server time